# Stretching Strings: Safe technique

Tags: guitar, maintenance

So, I've been told that stretching guitar strings shortly after fitting them is a useful technique for keeping them in tune for longer. I've recently started doing this after some advice online to do so and a distant memory of a tech at my local guitar shop pulling strings an alarming distance away from the guitar.

My concern is that pulling strings out, away from the guitar body, is a risk of bending the neck (like an archery bow). Pulling up or down, parallel to the body) feels like it may put some strain on the bridge, or pull the string out of place, damaging intonation.

What's the best way to ensure my tuning doesn't slip, but also avoid any long-term damage to the guitar?